# Starting an Activity from an Activity using an Intent spews uncaught errors

Tags: android

On my Main activity:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainAddWatchButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(audiovideo, CountyBrowser.class));
  }
});
```

CountyBrowser activity starts fine (and behaves fine, just as it should), but things like these spews out in LogCat:

```
10-11 19:10:41.182: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=se.ribit.bb/.CountyBrowser }
10-11 19:10:41.782: DEBUG/dalvikvm(368): GC freed 6313 objects / 354184 bytes in 114ms
10-11 19:10:41.812: INFO/dalvikvm(368): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
10-11 19:10:41.812: INFO/dalvikvm(368): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d3ec38 on null that has not been deactivated or closed
10-11 19:10:41.823: INFO/dalvikvm(368):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
10-11 19:10:41.823: INFO/dalvikvm(368):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-11 19:10:41.852: INFO/dalvikvm(368): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
10-11 19:10:41.862: INFO/dalvikvm(368): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: **Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d3dc80 on null that has not been deactivated or closed**
10-11 19:10:41.862: INFO/dalvikvm(368):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
10-11 19:10:41.873: INFO/dalvikvm(368):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-11 19:10:42.452: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity se.ribit.bb/.CountyBrowser: 1198 ms (total 1198 ms)
10-11 19:10:47.702: DEBUG/dalvikvm(206): GC freed 124 objects / 5424 bytes in 154ms
10-11 19:10:52.692: DEBUG/dalvikvm(105): GC freed 2292 objects / 133288 bytes in 107ms
```

I am using database and cursors, but the messages above contains zero information whether I'm doing something wrong or not. The activity works fine, except for these logs. If I run everything in debug-mode, the emulator throws me back to Eclipse all the time.

Am I missing something here? Anyone care for a guess of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to close the cursors before the Activity pauses. In your onPause method for the Activity that opens the new Activity, try closing the cursors.

```
void onPause(){
  myCursor1.close();
  myCursor2.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry I was a bit unclear in my but, but I'm using startManagingCursor() so I shouldn't have to bother about it.

After a lot of step-debugging I finally found the source of the error (see next post).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of step-debugging, I found the source of the error. I had this method:

```
private boolean doesColumnExist(String table, int id) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
  String query = String.format("SELECT count(*) FROM %s WHERE %s = %s",
                                table, C_ID, id);
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
  c.moveToFirst();
  return (c.getInt(0) == 1);
}
```

I'm not good at Java yet, so naively I thought the cursor was supposed to die by itself when this method returns, but I was obviously very wrong on this fact. I had to rewrite the method into this:

```
private boolean doesColumnExist(String table, int id) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
  String query = String.format("SELECT count(*) FROM %s WHERE %s = %s",
                                table, C_ID, id);
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
  c.moveToFirst();
  boolean retVal = (c.getInt(0) == 1);
  c.close();

  return retVal;
}
```

Now all the LogCat-fillings are gone.

I never realized I had to manually do a c.close(). Since I'm newcomer to Java, I thought Java's GC would handle it. Reading further in my Java-book proved I was wrong, very wrong.